# Wrong matrix output when writing on csv file only for the first line [C]

Tags: c, csv, pointers, matrix

I am writing a program that takes as input from the user names and answers associated for every candidate and print them on a .csv file as follow:

`name, answer A, answer B,..., answer Z.`

every name is stored in a matrix called `nome_cognome`;
every answer is stored in a matrix called `matrice_risposte`;

For some kind of reason I ignore, the program prints the wrong answer only for the last one of the first candidate (the "Z" question). Any other candidate has all the answers reported correctly.

what i tried to do: 
I debugged the program for 5 days without understanding the reason behind the problem. I searched the web for similar issues, i tried to modify the code, but i cannot solve it.
I usually write on forums as my last chance, if i cannot find any kind of solution.

I make the user checks if the inserted answers are correct for every candidate before proceeding with the next one. When printing the answers on screen, they are reported correctly. When printing on file it happens as described.

The following image clearly show what i am talking about
[image]

I typed for Paul all the answers as 1, while for marie i typed all the answers as 2.

The code shows the section where the program writes on the csv file (it is created).

```
FILE *file_risultati; //apertura file di testo
strcat(corso,".csv");
file_risultati=fopen(corso, "w");

for (j=0;j<iscritti;j++){

    p=0;
    while(nome_cognome[j][p]!='\n')
    {
    fprintf(file_risultati,"%c", nome_cognome[j][p]);
    p=p+1;
    }
    fprintf(file_risultati,",");


    for(i=0; i<22; i++)
    {
        fprintf(file_risultati,"%d,", matrice_risposte[j][i]);
    }
    if(j != (iscritti-1)){
        fprintf(file_risultati,"\n");
    }
}
    fclose(file_risultati); //chiusura file di testo
```

The following code is the complete program so you can check it all and verify what i said.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char corso[100];
char acquisizione_nome [40];
char domande[]= "ABCDEFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVZ";
int iscritti;
int risposta;

int i;
int j;
int k=1;
int p;

// variabili variazione risposta

int modifica_risposta = 1;
int risposta_precedente;
char risposta_modificata;
char domande_min[]="abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvz";

int main()
{
    printf("Program written by Gianluca Gregnol\n\n");
    printf("Raccolta del fabbisogno formativo\n\n");
    printf("Digitare il corso di interesse: ");
    gets(corso);
    printf("Digitare numero di iscritti al corso: ");
    scanf("%d", &iscritti);

    char nome_cognome[iscritti][40];
    int matrice_risposte[iscritti][21];

    // processo di inserimento votazioni //
    for (k=0;k <(iscritti);k++)
    {
        printf("\n iscritto ");
        printf("%d \n\n", k+1);
        printf("nome e cognome: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(acquisizione_nome,40,stdin);

        for (i=0; i<40; i++)
        {
            nome_cognome[k][i]= acquisizione_nome[i];
        }

        for (i=0; i<22; i++)
        {
            printf("\nvoto della domanda ");
            printf("%c: ", domande[i]);
            scanf("%d", &risposta);

            while (risposta<0 || risposta>3)
            {
                printf("\n VOTO NON VALIDO!\n i voti validi sono: 0,1,2,3\n inserire nuovamente il voto per la domanda ");
                printf("%c:", domande[i]);
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%d", &risposta);
            }
            matrice_risposte[k][i]=risposta;

        }

//stampa le risposte attuali per permetterne il controllo
        printf("\nLe risposte attualmente inserite sono: \n");

        for (i=0; i<22; i++)
        {
            printf("%c  ", domande[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        for (i=0; i<22; i++)
        {
            printf("%d  ", matrice_risposte[k][i]);
        }

        printf("\nDesideri modificare delle risposte? \n No = 0 \n Si = 1 \n");
        printf("Risposta: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &modifica_risposta);


// controlla se l'utente vuole cambiare delle risposte
        while(modifica_risposta == 1){

            printf("\n\nQuale risposta vuoi modificare?\n");
            printf("Risposta: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c", &risposta_modificata);

            for(i=0; i<22; i++){

                if(risposta_modificata == domande_min[i] || risposta_modificata == domande[i]){

                printf("\nIndica il nuovo valore della domanda %c: ", domande[i]);
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%d", &risposta);
                while (risposta < 0 || risposta > 3)
                {
                    printf("\n VOTO NON VALIDO!\n i voti validi sono: 0,1,2,3\n inserire nuovamente il voto per la domanda ");
                    printf("%c:", domande[i]);
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%d", &risposta);
                }
                risposta_precedente = matrice_risposte[k][i] ;
                matrice_risposte[k][i] = risposta;

                printf(" -- Risposta modificata correttamente --\n\n");

                }
            }

            printf("\nDesideri modificare delle risposte? \n No = 0 \n Si = 1 \n");
            printf("Risposta: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d", &modifica_risposta);


        } //main  while

    }

// processo scrittura su file

    FILE *file_risultati; //apertura file di testo
    strcat(corso,".csv");
    file_risultati=fopen(corso, "w");

    for (j=0;j<iscritti;j++){

        p=0;
        while(nome_cognome[j][p]!='\n')
        {
        fprintf(file_risultati,"%c", nome_cognome[j][p]);
        p=p+1;
        }
        fprintf(file_risultati,",");


        for(i=0; i<22; i++)
        {
            fprintf(file_risultati,"%d,", matrice_risposte[j][i]);
        }
        if(j != (iscritti-1)){
            fprintf(file_risultati,"\n");
        }
    }
        fclose(file_risultati); //chiusura file di testo

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

in line 32:

```
int matrice_risposte[iscritti][21];
```

change `21` to `22`

**Explanation:**

I noticed (from the attached picture) you have 22 questions but declared a 21 element array. In most languages multi-dimensional arrays are implemented by serialization. So matrice_risposte[1][22] is actually matrice_risposte[2][0]. You did not notice the bug because you first print the results then overwrite the last result with next round of input.

Comment: it seems to solve the problem, but i have a doubt. vectors in C start from 0, so the matrix matrice_risposte[iscritti][21] should have 22 columns. i now see that the matrix itself should be initialized as matrice_risposte[iscritti-1][21] to take into account all the subjects and the 22 answers for every candidate, otherwhise it will take 1 candidate more than necessary. i don't understand that part of your answer "So matrice_risposte[1][22] is actually matrice_risposte[2][0]. "  but i supposed it is related to the consideration i'm doing in this reply.

Comment: @airman01 An array declared as `int array[2][22]` has room for 2 "rows" with 22 "columns" each. However, valid indexes for the "rows" are `[0-1]` and for "columns" are `[0-21]`. So trying to access `array[0][22]` is an error since `22` is not a valid index. As would  `array[2][0]` be an error.